# mousemove on body stops mouseenter on childs

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I'm trying to use `mousemove` event on `document.body` to change the cursor (I'm not using CSS because I want to edit the new cursor based on its position).

This part works just fine,
but when I try to detect `mouseenter` on other elements whitch are body childs, I run into a problem, the `mouseenter` ( or `mouseleave` ) doesn't get fired off unless I move the mouse too fast, and also they fire off both together...

Here is my HTML:

```html
  <style>
  #cursor {
    position: absolute;
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    background: #595959;
    border-radius: 9999px;
    z-index: 9999;
  }

  #test {
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid red;
  }

  </style>

  <div id="cursor"></div>
  <div id="test"></div>
```

and my Js:

```js
const cursor = document.querySelector('#cursor');
const test = document.querySelector('#test');

function onBodyMouseMove(e) {
  cursor.style.left = e.clientX - 7.5 + 'px';
  cursor.style.top = e.clientY - 7.5 + 'px';
};

function enter(e) {
  console.log('mouse entered');
}

function leave(e) {
  console.log('mouse left');
}

document.body.addEventListener('mousemove', onBodyMouseMove);
test.addEventListener('mouseenter', enter);
test.addEventListener('mouseleave', leave);
```

you can check out the pen: https://codepen.io/hamid331994/pen/ExgGwqO

#### Note:

using `e.stopPropagation();` doesn't work

adding `{ passive: false }` doesn't work neither

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with CSS. Your mouse cursor is still above element #cursor not above element #test and when you move your cursor faster that means DOM was not updated your #cursor element position.

When you will add `pointer-events: none;` to `#cursor` then will help.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `body` dose not really count as much as `window` in this case.

So you could fix this problem by simple adding this line.

```
window.addEventListener('mousemove', onBodyMouseMove);
```

Comment: this didn't work in my case, the problem is found and explained in the answer from Krystian Sztadhaus